# Models of inflation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, computational-physics, cosmological-inflation, klein-gordon-equation

I'm trying to get an overview of cosmological models which include inflation. My aim is to study the numerics of nonlinear Klein- Gordon equations which in fact are the Friedmann equations in the FRLW metric. 
\begin{equation}
\ddot{\phi}+3 \dot{\phi} H + V'(\phi) =0.
\end{equation}

Here $H$ stands for the Hubble constant and $\phi$ is representing the inflation field. I know there are several anstatzes for the inflation, especially I'm interested in the different potentials $V$ which occur in different models and why they are chosen this way (just a rough argument).

Comment: A little dated, but this paper includes many of the popular phenomenological models: https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0510441

Comment: Forms of the potential are generally chosen because they reproduce observations (and vice versa, potentials have been ruled out because they make non-physical predictions).

Comment: There's also this compendium of models from just after the first results from the Planck satellite: https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3787